# How do I create a byte[][](java) in C using JNI and pass it to an object

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I know how to create a `jobject` and would like to convert an existing `char **` into a corresponding `byte[][]` and pass it to the `jobject` using JNI.

How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jnistring.html](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jnistring.html#multi) describes the about Multi-Dimensional Arrays in JNI